# Динамическое изменение хостов в apache при помощи mod_macro

Tags: apache2, apache-modules

Так уж вышло, что у меня мало опыта в linux, а мне часто приходится настраивать хосты. И я узнал, что можно динамически их настраивать при помощи модуля mod_macro. Читаю сейчас здесь: https://serverfault.com/questions/64656/using-variables-in-apache-config-files-to-reduce-duplication. Если следовать инструкции из ответа, то файл  vhost.macro с содержимым ниже нужно положить в /etc/apache2/conf.d/vhost.macro:

```
<Macro VHost $host $port>
 <VirtualHost $host:$port>
  ServerName $host
  DocumentRoot /var/vhosts/$host

  <Directory /var/vhosts/$host>
  # do something here...
  </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
</Macro>
```

Но у меня нет папки conf.d в apache2. Даже если создать папку или просто закинуть файл в apache2 и создать файл /etc/apache2/sites-available/vhost.mysite.com со строкой `Use VHost vhost.mysite.com 80`, сделать рестарт и в конце `sudo a2ensite api-test`, то будет *ERROR: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/api-test.conf is a dangling symlink!
ERROR: Site api-test does not exist!*

Здесь тоже детали не проясняются: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_macro.html

Как правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию, mod_macro не включен, поэтому надо включить: `sudo a2enmod macro`

Затем перезапуск apache `systemctl reload apache2`

Нужно создать файл v-host-macro.conf и положить его в */etc/apache2/conf-available*, содержание его следующее:

```
<Macro VHost $dir $domain>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin <-- Ваш email -->  
     ServerName $domain

     DocumentRoot $dir/$domain

     <Directory />
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
         Require all granted
     </Directory>

     <Directory $dir/$domain>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
         AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
         allow from all
         Require all granted
     </Directory>

     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
     <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
         AllowOverride All
         Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog $dir/$domain/error.log

     # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
     # alert, emerg.
     LogLevel warn

     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
</Macro>
```

Здесь же применяем `sudo a2enconf vhost-macro` и снова перезапускаем apache.

Переходим в */etc/apache2/sites-available*, создаем файл site-example.loc.conf и прописываем `Use VHost <-- папка с проектом --> <-- домен -->`

Включить свой сайт: `sudo a2ensite site-example.loc`

Перезапустить apache

Добавить строку в etc/hosts: `127.0.0.1 site-example.loc`